# Create a partition with read-only permission on VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

I'm dealing with a system needs to have and HDD with two partitions on it.

One partition is a free space. Every file operations can be performed on it.

The other partition is like a back-up partition and it should be read-only.

I had a look on **xbdCreatePartition** functions parameters, but it does not have an option argument.

To make long story short, Is it possible to create a partition mode to read-only on vxworks 7?

Regards